# nisNetgroupTriple not returned by getent -s sss netgroup

Tags: ldap, sssd

I'm testing openldap as a source for ssh logins and sudo rules using sssd.

So far i can use LDAP to auth (password and key) and sudo based on rules from LDAP.

But i want to be able to use netgroups as well to control where users have access to login to.

When using ALL for the host in the LDAP sudo rule the user can sudo. If i create a nisNetgroup that i will use in the sudo rule then the user cannot sudo.

This is what i have in my sssd conf for netgroups:

```
sudo_provider = ldap

####-- netgroups
ldap_sudo_include_netgroups = True
ldap_netgroup_search_base = ou=HostGroups,dc=redacted,dc=com
ldap_netgroup_object_class = nisNetgroup
ldap_netgroup_triple = nisNetgroupTriple
```

i have `netgroup: sss` in /etc/nsswitch.conf file

My nisNetgroup in LDAP:

```
dn: cn=blabla,ou=HostGroups,dc=redacted,dc=com
cn: blabla
nisNetgroupTriple: test-app01,,
objectClass: nisNetgroup
objectClass: top
```

in sssd log i can see the triple beign recorded:

```
[sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding netgroup triple [test-app01,,] to attributes of [blabla].
```

But when i run getent i don't see the triple:

```
$getent -s sss netgroup blabla
blabla
```

And the user cannot sudo.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was with the triple, it needs to be encompassed by parentheses to work.